# C++ function with variable return type using 'auto'

Tags: c++, auto, return-type-deduction

I'm trying to write a function that returns various types depending on the if-statement.

```
auto parseParameterValue(QString aParameterValueString, int aParameterType)
{
    if(aParameterType == 0)
    {
        int result = aParameterValueString.toInt();
        return result;
    }
    else if(aParameterType == 1)
    {
        double result = aParameterValueString.toDouble();
        return result; // <------- compilation error
    }
    else
    {
        return aParameterValueString;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately what I get is:

> 1. Warning: 'parseParameterValue' function uses 'auto' type specifier without trailing return type
> 2. Error at second return:  inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'int' and then 'double'

Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Return type deduction works at compile time solely. You need rather something like `boost::any`.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. With `auto` **compiler** will deduce right return type but it must be consistent (unless you want to go with a `QVariant`...)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks a lot! I've completely forgotten about the `QVariant` - that should work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, a function can only have one return type.

Note that processing of a function return type must happen at compile time, but your function uses values that can't be known until run time.

Answer (score 4):

You could return an erasure type, such as `boost::any`, which can store any type. Your code would then look like this

```
boost::any parseParameterValue(QString aParameterValueString, int aParameterType)
{
    switch(aParameterType) {
    default: return {aParameterValueString};
    case 0:  return {aParameterValueString.toInt()};
    case 1:  return {aParameterValueString.toDouble()};
    }
}
```